# how to start a new activity by bottom navigation

Tags: android

I want to start new activity by bottom navigation bar but it not working.

I have checked many tutorials also, but do not know where problem the problem is.

Here is my code.

```
public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    Intent i = new Intent(display.this, Addab.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell us what is not working exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.navigation_home:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Abc.class));
           Break;
       case R.id.navigation_camera:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, Cab.class));
           Break;

   }
   finish();
   return true;
}
```

Also Refer here-->
https://blog.fossasia.org/using-activities-with-bottom-navigation-view-in-phimpme-android/

Answer (score 0):

instead of `break;` use `return true;`